# Sequential numbering for each record

Tags: ms-access, sequential

I have contracts and I want each contract to have its purchase orders sequenced

I just can’t get it to work

What I tried to do is make a calculated field in my form using the control source

=DMax([PO],[POt],[POt].[Contract number])+1

By that I thought if I can make it read the biggest PO for that contract to add 1 to it

But I keep getting #name? Errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
=DMax("[PO]","[POt]","[Contract number] = " & [Contract number] & "")+1
```

where `[Contract number]` is the field holding the current contract number.